# why are my responsive images stretching vertically in ie8

Tags: html, css, response

I have a number of image with a width of 100%.  In every other browser this means that the image scales to fit its container, but in ie8 the images stretch vertically.  Any ideas why? What can I do to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to control images across multiple browsers more easily using a tool from [imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net/). Follow their installation instructions using NuGet, and then when referencing the image in your HTML use link parameters:

```
<a href="file.jpg?w=100&height=100&mode=max">
```

Check their basic commands documentation for other parameter options. I've used this tool for responsive web design and it scales fine using width, height, and mode parameters.  see an example I implemented [here](http://myocremodeling.com).